# How to create a localhost in Node.js? And why mine is not working?

Tags: node.js

I'm not able to create a localhost for Node.js. Following are the thing I had completed:

I had created a file named server.js and the code is as follows:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request, respone){
  respone.writeHead(200, {'Content-type':'text/plan'});
  response.write('Hello Node JS Server Response');
  response.end("Hello Sowmay Response ended");

}).listen(7000);
```

Then I had run this javascript script file on node.js cmd prompt as follows:

```
C:\Users\Guest\Desktop\First-Node>node server.js
```

After that I tried opening the local host on my windows PC from this link: **http://localhost:7000**

Result:
This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.

Where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Is there any error from Node itself? port may be already in use, and you have a type in Content-Type, it is "text/plain" instead of "text/plan".

Comment: When I type node server in the cmd prompt it takes me to another line with a blinking cursor (or whatever). There's no print of the words out on the cmd prompt. Not error, neither success.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in your code.
I guess your console would output :
undefined has not a function "writeHead"

Becuase `respone.writeHead(200, {'Content-type':'text/plan'});` lack a 's'.
Please use:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request, response){
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-type':'text/plan'});
  response.write('Hello Node JS Server Response');
  response.end("Hello Sowmay Response ended");

}).listen(7000);
```

and try again

Comment: I changed it and tried again. Not working. What may be the possible problem? I had created an another server with different with 3000 number and it's working now.

Comment: @SowmayJain You can use `netstat -aqo` to check whether 7000 has been occupied by another program. And I suggest you read the output from the nodejs CLI, which may tell you why it doesn't work.